# JavaFX multiple titled panes in a vbox with scene builder (accordion-like)

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new to JavaFX and trying to have an accordion-like form, but with the possibility to expand multiple titled panes at a time. As I understood it is not possible with accordion, so I'm trying the suggested method of having titled panes inside a vbox.

I'm designing the form using scene builder 1.1. The issue is that titled panes are not "bound" like in accordion; if I collapse one, the rest do not scroll up, and an empty space is left in the place of the collapsed pane.

Any ideas are welcome how to fix this is scene builder.

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you post your code? (Also, SceneBuilder 1.1 is *way* out of date. You should upgrade to a [newer version](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/).)

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a newer Scene Builder.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue with the scroll/empty space you can try the following:

```
titledPane.setMinHeight(200);
titledPane.expandedProperty().addListener((observable, wasExpanded, isExpanded) -> 
    titledPane.setMinHeight(isExpanded ? 200 : Region.USE_PREF_SIZE));
```

But I suggest you also set

```
titledPane.setAnimated(false);
```

Otherwhise the result is not really smooth.

In my case the TitledPane's strech to fill the VBox:

[Just opened TitledPane's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNdat.png)

[One collapsed TitledPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycwSu.png)

If all Panes are collapsed they move to the top.